# iOS keychain not restored

Tags: ios, keychain

I've provided an update for an application that use keychain in iOS. Please note that the update does not have anything to do in the keychain code.

**The problem** :  when some people install the new application, their previous keychain data are not here anymore, at least from the app. point of view I couldn't acces to these people devices so I can't say if the keychain still have this data.

**Me** : 
- How I test : I remove the app. I reinstall the app either from Xcode, form itunes, by drag and drop from Finder. 
- I've tested it successfully on my targets, described below. 
- I also tried to simulated as closest as possible with a "ad-hoc" profile

=> Results from all this:  I always retrieve my previous data

*Nota Bene* :

The application was originally developped in iOS 3 and now I use Xcode 4 with iOS 4.3
Thus, from Apple :

> The keychain data is also backed up.

cf : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW5

__*_*__*_*__*_*_*Targets* __*_*__*_*__*_*___

People devices with problem: Iphones with iOS 4.3.5 (8L1).

Mine (no problem) : Ipad iOS 4.3.5 (8L1), iPod touch 4.2, simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After many days of rock'n roll with Apple doc,tests, and experimentations I finally understood why there is have different behaviours with keychains.

The main idea is that, as often with Apple : "all is in certificate", not in code, not in project itself.

Important for you to know :

- **The keychain access is linked to a certificate**, the password grant you to some of data
- if for historical reasons you have to use more than 1 certificate, you have to create a dedicated entitlements plist that will include all of them cf[1] and beware that older must be 1st in list
- iOS has 1 keychain (in Mac you can see many with the keychain app)

Therefore when you use your ad-hoc profile with the good cert. you will be able to read previous saved data again.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/keychain-group-access.html

Comment: The keychain access is not linked to a certificate. It is linked to the app id, formatted as `<prefix>.<bundle id>`. The app ID, and the certificate are linked from the provisioning profile.